# How to count the levels of hierarchy in R?

Tags: r, igraph, hierarchical-data

I have a panel data which contains 130 companies' departments in 15 years. The data includes the edge lists of these companies. How do I count every companies' hierarchical levels and identify every department's level in the hierarchy in R?

```
    source  target
1   A       B
2   A       C
3   A       D
4   B       E
5   B       F
6   C       G
7   D       H
8   D       I
9   D       J
10  G       K
```

In this case, the top is A, and the bottom is K. The company's hierarchical level is 4. I hope I can create two variables in the panel data of the departments. Like this:

```
    year    compname    department  complevel   departlevel
1   2000    Ben Corp.   A           4           1
2   2000    Ben Corp.   B           4           2
3   2000    Ben Corp.   C           4           2
4   2000    Ben Corp.   D           4           2
5   2000    Ben Corp.   E           4           3
6   2000    Ben Corp.   F           4           3
7   2000    Ben Corp.   G           4           3
8   2000    Ben Corp.   H           4           3
9   2000    Ben Corp.   I           4           3
10  2000    Ben Corp.   J           4           3
11  2000    Ben Corp.   K           4           4
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this:

```
library(igraph)
df <- read.table(text = '
source  target
1   A       B
2   A       C
3   A       D
4   B       E
5   B       F
6   C       G
7   D       H
8   D       I
9   D       J
10  G       K
')
```

convert to graph

```
g <- graph.data.frame(df)
```

get rank table: (you need to manually input the 'top' node)

```
data.frame(node = names(shortest.paths(g)[,'A']), rank = shortest.paths(g)[,'A']+1)
  node rank
A    A    1
B    B    2
C    C    2
D    D    2
G    G    3
E    E    3
F    F    3
H    H    3
I    I    3
J    J    3
K    K    4
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the data.tree package:

```
library(data.tree)
df <- read.table(text = '
source  target
1   A       B
2   A       C
3   A       D
4   B       E
5   B       F
6   C       G
7   D       H
8   D       I
9   D       J
10  G       K
')

tree <- FromDataFrameNetwork(df)
print(tree, "level")
```

This will give you:

```
       levelName level
1  A                 1
2   ¦--B             2
3   ¦   ¦--E         3
4   ¦   °--F         3
5   ¦--C             2
6   ¦   °--G         3
7   ¦       °--K     4
8   °--D             2
9       ¦--H         3
10      ¦--I         3
11      °--J         3
```